# Edit the User Information List without being a Site Collection Administrator

Tags: 2013, permissions, site-collection, user-information-list

I am managing a SharePoint 2013 site collection, I want to allow a group of users to edit the User Information List through a script, but I get Access Denied errors, even though the group has Full Control. We are not using the User Profile Service, this is specific to the site collection.

Can you only edit the User Information List if you are a Site Collection Administrator?

Answer (score 2):

Don't do it. That's a system list and managed by SharePoint. If you mess with it one of two things will probably happen:

- SharePoint will simply overwrite your changes
- You will break the site

Whatever end goal you're trying to accomplish, there's a more supportable way to do it than editing the user info list.